# Elasticsearch: suggest users based on likes

Tags: elasticsearch, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to model user suggestion system in elasticsearch which takes into account users likes and profile.

I have the user structure like this:

```
user: { 
    id: 232344,
    location: 'New York',
    likes: [4545, 3434, 343]
}
```

I want to suggest users based on below three concepts:

1) users who liked me.

2) users like the one i liked. (similar location, etc)

3) mutual likes. (user a like user x. user b likes user x. suggest user a to b and vice versa.)

I have read about `More like this` query in elasticsearch but i'm not sure if it can take into account all these scenarios.

How can i model these things in elasticsearch queries or should i consider using a graph database like neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Users who like me. Suppose that my id is `1`

```
{ 
    "query": {
        "term" : { "likes" : 1 }
    }
}
```

2)  Check [more like this api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html#search-more-like-this). Given a document id and a set of fields it responds with similar documents to the given one. There are lots of options so I recommend to read the documentation and see if it fits your use case.

3) mutual likes: Suppose I'm `a` and I liked these users `[1, 3, 5]`. This query will return `b` if `b` also liked one of those ids.

```
{ 
    "query": {
        "term" : { "likes" : [1, 3, 5] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I liked the approach. Is there a way we can model all the three queries in one? I need to decide if i should be running these queries in background and save all the info in redis. If we can do it in one query and still be performant, i would prefer to live query compared to background jobs.

Comment: You can group queries with [multisearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search). Elasticsearch will run 3 queries but you have to make only one request. If you go for this solution look [more like this query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) instead of more like this api

Comment: Awesome! Thanks man. I will benchmark with some random data and see how much time it takes.